# How to run a long running grep, pipe the result into less and put everything into background?

Tags: shell, less, background-process

I often find myself in the situation where I need to find a code base for a given symbol like so:

```
find src/galio -not -path './src/stapi-sdk/apilib/* -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*(\.hpp|\.hxx|\.cpp|\.cxx|\.h|\.c|\.ma?k|\.sh|makefile)' | xargs egrep --colour=always -Hn 'NUM_EXTERITY_FLAGS' | less -R
```

The `find`/`grep` combination can take quite a while and I'd like to put the whole chain into the background (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and `bg`) and check back later to look at the result.

However, the whole job is immediately "Stopped" again after putting it into the background with `bg`. Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to take a look at a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend `screen` for this kind of situation. (Or run the command in a different window if that's feasible for you.)

To start a detached session, just enter `screen`. Then type your command but without the `&` to background it. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd> to detach the running session. Use `screen -ls` to list existing sessions and `screen -r` to reattach.

Comment: Hmm, isn't there another way? Why is less going straight to the stopped state? I'm too lazy to start a new screen session just for the one command. :D

Comment: Write the output to `/tmp/somefile` (instead of piping it to `less`). Use `less /tmp/somefile` to check back every so often. Use job control notifications to discover that the job has finished.

Comment: Yes, that'd be one option, thanks. But again, out of pure laziness / convenience, I'd rather end up not having lots of spurious files lying around. (I typically do dozens of searches like this in a day and I'm looking to run different search simultanenously).

Comment: Create a (trivial) script to parameterise your searches. Use a known directory to store the searches, e.g. `/tmp/mysearches`. Add a `find /tmp/mysearches -type f -mtime +2 -delete 2>/dev/null` in the script to keep it reasonably tidy.

Answer (score 1):

The Two problems with less slowing your search are pipe wait and opening standard out/error for reading. In normal operation less will read enough to fill a screen and stop reading until you advance to the next page. This works fine unless you are reading from a pipe and the program writing to the pipe notices the pipe id full and sleeps until the pipe is read and is really slow about writing enough to fill the next page. The two easiest ways to change this behavior by less is to search for something that is not there or to calculate the size of standard input. Both will read the full file in. The next problem is that to control less it needs to receive commands from the keyboard, so it opens standard out or standard error for reading. This is odd but works just fine (with a few safeguards that less takes care of), but  now less has a file handle open for reading pointing to the controlling tty (which you want when controlling less) that the shell's job control notices when you put things into the background and when less tries to read a key the shell puts it to sleep. You may be able to get around this by searching for the end of file in less before putting it in the background.